# Verilog - Unexpected behaviour on first clock cycle

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog

I've done a bit of experimenting with Verilog recently, and I ran into a problem where it doesn't behave as I'd expect. In one of my modules, I have code like the following that is designed to simply track odd/even cycles, because I'm performing operations that take 2 cycles each:

```
reg even_cycle = 0;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    even_cycle <= ~even_cycle;
    if(even_cycle)
        //do something
end
```

The expected behaviour: On the first clock cycle, `even_cycle` is flipped, which, due to it being a register should see it continue to show zero until the **next cycle**, where its new value of 1 will be clocked.

What really happens: On the positive edge of the first clock cycle, `even_cycle` is **already set to 1**

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but could anyone please explain this behaviour? It seems to go against my understanding of registers. How can a reg's value appear to be updated on the same cycle it's assigned?

As a bonus question, if I have a clock signal that I want to pass to a module conditionally, is the following a bad way of doing it? If so, is there a recommended way?

```
input clk_in; //always running

wire cond_clk;

assign cond_clk = some_condition ? clk_in : 0
```

When run in the simulator and I stop the clock (i.e the condition becomes false), cond_clk shows as a vertical line in the simulator, as if it's high for a tiny period at the beginning of the cycle.

Comment: Which line is doing something you didn't expect?  The `even_cycle <= ~even_cycle` or the `if(even_cycle)` ?

Comment: For your bonus question, FPGA logic blocks are designed with "clock enable" signals, e.g. `if (some_condition && posedge clk)`.  Clock gating risks glitching, unless you use the clock gating features associated with global clock trees.  Which is not a bad tradeoff -- the advantage of clock gating over clock enable is power-saving, and for that to be worthwhile, it has to affect a large amount of circuitry (hence global clock tree)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you, I will do some reading on that subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation behaves as it should.  At the positive edge of `clk`, the nonblocking assignment is executed, updating the `even_cycle` signal with its new value, which is always the inverse of its previous value.

At time 0, you set `even_cycle` to 0 in the `reg` declaration line.  It stays at 0 until the 1st positive edge of `clk`.  At that time, `even_cycle` becomes 1.

Consider this simple code:

```
module tb;

reg clk = 0;
always #5 clk++;

reg even_cycle = 0;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    even_cycle <= ~even_cycle;
end

initial #500 $finish;

endmodule
```

[image]

Assuming `clk` is 0 at time 0 and goes to 1 at time 5, `even_cycle` goes high at time 5 as well.  It then remains at 1 until the 2nd positive edge of `clk` at time 15.  This code models a positive-edge triggered flip flop.

Comment: Thanks, I think that confused me because it almost seems like the register behaves differently on the first cycle than on subsequent ones. Considering this normal behaviour, how might I ensure that `even_cycle` remains at zero for the first clock cycle as I was incorrectly anticipating it would? Do I have to use some additional logic to handle it?

Comment: @Triforcer  toggle on falling edge of the clock

Comment: Also: any process that is synchronous to a clock will see the *old* value of any signal that changes with the same rising edge. So if you output `even_cycle` to the console, the first value you should see in the log is `0`, and any other logic that is synchronous to `clk` would also register `even_cycle` as `0` with the first rising edge.